# Paypal - "ID token context does not have required scope" error when trying to render paypal button using saved payment info

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I have been trying to save customer payment details on a site, so that if a customer is logged in they can pay with a single click, instead of having to log in to paypal. To do so I have been following the official paypal guide: https://developer.paypal.com/beta/vault/during-purchase/js-sdk/paypal/

I was able to successfully save payment details. The problem is that when I try to use the saved customer_id to use those saved payment details, I get the following error: "Error: cannot get vault - ID token context does not have required scope".

What I did was the following:

1. Generate an id_token and access_token by sending a request to https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token and specifying response_type=id_token
2. When rendering the paypal button, pass the generated id_token to the script tags data-user-id-token attribute.
3. I click the paypal button on the website. This sends a request to my backend server which generates an order by sending a request to https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/checkout/orders/. When generating the order I use the generated access_token as a Bearer token in the "Authorization" header, as well as pass the following payment_source.paypal configuration:

```
"paypal": {
    "attributes": {
      "vault": {
        "store_in_vault": "ON_SUCCESS",
        "usage_type": "MERCHANT",
        "customer_type": "CONSUMER"
      }
    }
```

4. I get an order id in the response. I pass this order id back to the client side, where the paypal sdk initates a payment flow using this id.
5. I finish the payment flow, and on success call my server's captureOrder endpoint. This calls https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/checkout/orders/$id/capture, where $id is the orderID used before. I also pass the Beares access_token generated in the first step. This request returns a response containing a generated user ID that looks something like this: 560837847
6. I send another request to https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token, this time passing a target_customer_id parameter in the request's body. The value of the parameter is the customerId generated in the 5th step.
7. I render the page with the paypal button again, this time passing the new id_token to the script tags data-user-id-token attribute.
8. The error "Error: cannot get vault - ID token context does not have required scope" appears in the developer tools console.

I have turned on "Accept payments" on the Paypal developer console as well as Vault functionality: [image]

The id_token generated in the 6th step has the following scopes:

```
https://uri.paypal.com/services/invoicing
https://uri.paypal.com/services/vault/payment-tokens/read
https://uri.paypal.com/services/disputes/read-buyer
https://uri.paypal.com/services/payments/realtimepayment
https://uri.paypal.com/services/disputes/update-seller
openid 
https://uri.paypal.com/services/payments/payment/authcapture
https://uri.paypal.com/services/disputes/read-seller
Braintree:Vault
https://uri.paypal.com/services/payments/refund
https://api.paypal.com/v1/vault/credit-card
https://api.paypal.com/v1/payments/.*
https://uri.paypal.com/payments/payouts
https://uri.paypal.com/services/vault/payment-tokens/readwrite
https://api.paypal.com/v1/vault/credit-card/.*
https://uri.paypal.com/services/shipping/trackers/readwrite
https://uri.paypal.com/services/subscriptions
https://uri.paypal.com/services/applications/webhooks
```

I cannot find any information online about what else I should do to make this work.

Comment: Have you tried a new REST app?

Comment: I ended up contacting support, they turned on an option on my account that I had no ability to turn on myself.